# C# Dictionary to C++ std::map

Tags: c#, c++, dictionary, stl, stdmap

I have a Dictionary variable in my C# file **Rec.cs** defined as:

```
Dictionary<string, PrepDumpLoadItem> pPrepDumpLoadList
```

This `pPrepDumpLoadList` is filled with keys and values like following

```
foreach (XElement element in root.Elements())
                {
                    PrepDumpLoadItem item = new PrepDumpLoadItem();
                    item.Name = element.Name.ToString();

                    string isDumpMode = GetValueString(element, "Dump", "enabled");
                    if (isDumpMode == "1")
                    {
                        item.PrepDumpLoadMode += PrepDumpLoadModeType.DUMP;
                        item.HeaderFile = GetValueString(element, "Dump", "header");
                        item.DataFile = GetValueString(element, "Dump", "data");
                        //pPrepDumpLoadList.Add(item.Name, item);
                    }

                    string isLoadMode = GetValueString(element, "Load", "enabled");
                    if (isLoadMode == "1")
                    {
                        item.PrepDumpLoadMode += PrepDumpLoadModeType.LOAD;
                        item.HeaderFile = GetValueString(element, "Load", "header");
                        item.DataFile = GetValueString(element, "Load", "data");
                        //pPrepDumpLoadList.Add(item.Name, item);
                    }

                    pPrepDumpLoadList.Add(item.Name, item);
                }
```

After the code above, the `pPrepDumpLoadList` has 12 entries, which means its count == 12;

Afterwards it passed to a C++ file **WrapperRec.cpp**, in which each of its entries is supposed to get extracted, and passed/copied to a C++ `std::map` variable `PrepDumpLoadList`. This is defined as

```
std::map<std::string, PrepDumpLoadItem> PrepDumpLoadList;
```

within the structure of `SRecParameters` in SRecParameters.h

Here is how `PrepDumpLoadList` looks like under the debug mode (visual studio 2015):

[image]
which looks good. The `recon` is passed as an argument like

```
void WrappedRecon::CreateImpl( ScanParameters scan,
                           ReconParameters recon,
                           ScannerParameters scanner,
                           MessageHandler^ msgHandler
                         )
```

and I believe it is an variable of a structure identical/similar to `SRecParameters`.

However, I have difficulty extracting the entries from `PrepDumpLoadList`, the Dictionary variable from the C#.

I have tried

```
map<std::string, PrepDumpLoadItem>::iterator it = recon.PrepDumpLoadList.begin();
```

but the red wiggle appears underneath the `recon`, and compiling error says **error C2228: left of '.begin' must have class/struct/union**

I am really confused about what is happening here. I am just trying to something like

```
for (int i = 0; i<recon.PrepDumpLoadList->Count; ++i) {

    CopyString(item.Name, recon.PrepDumpLoadList[i].Name, sizeof(item.Name));

    item.PrepDumpLoadMode = static_cast<DumpLoadModeType>(recon.PrepDumpLoadList[i].PrepDumpLoadMode);

    CopyString(item.HeaderFile, recon.PrepDumpLoadList[i].HeaderFile, sizeof(item.HeaderFile));
    CopyString(item.DataFile, recon.PrepDumpLoadList[i].DataFile, sizeof(item.DataFile));

    reconParams.PrepDumpLoadList.push_back(item);
}
```

extracting information from the Dictionary variable and push it back to a std::map variable. Anyone can give some pointer where the problem is and how to solve it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't suppose `recon` is defined as `SRecParameters recon();`. A [mcve] is always appreciated.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920933/cpp-cli-convert-stdmap-to-net-dictionary

Comment: @chris Sorry, I added some explanation.

Comment: It looks like `PrepDumpLoadList` is a pointer. Try using `->` instead of `.` to access it's members, like your doing in the for loop line. Though we need to see some more code to be sure.

Comment: I actually tried "->", however, it does not show find(), or begin()......Instead, it only shows Count, .... as if it is not a std::map/Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a walk around by creating a `List` in C#, then process (marshal) each item in this `List`. and put them in a C++ `std::map`.